# convert date string into the actual date format?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, momentjs

I have called an API and then get a date which is string format like **'15/07/21-23:59:59'**. But I want to convert this string into the actual date format like this:

```
**15/07/21** OR **2009-06-01T10:00:00.000**.
```

so how can I achieve this?

Comment: There are many questions already about [parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+how+to+parse+a+date) and [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+how+to+format+a+date) date strings. What have you tried? `'15/07/21-23:59:59'.substring(0,8)` will do for the first example.

Comment: You might try `new Date(...('15/07/21-23:59:59'.split(/\W/).slice(0,3).reverse().reduce((acc, v, i) => {acc.push(i==0? '20'+v : i==1? --v : v); return acc;}, []))).toLocaleDateString('en-CA')` which gives 2021-07-05.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange to see a response returning a formatted date expression. By the way, your task would be easily done with [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/). Here is my snippet:

```js
// since your date format is not a standard one, you would have to pass an
// instruction of your date format as a second parameter to the moment constructor
const momentDate = moment('15/07/21-23:59:59', 'DD/MM/YY-HH:mm:ss');

momentDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'); // => "15/07/2021"
momentDate.format(`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`); // => "2021-07-Th'T'23:59:59.000+07:00"
```

Answer (score -1):

you can pass this string to a Date object as follow:

```
var date = new Date(YOUR STRING);
```

or you can use Date.parse() method if it does not work:

```
Date.parse('04 Dec 1995 00:12:00 GMT');
```

Comment: See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)